# Are there any WIFI based Speakers which connect to Windows using wifi only instead of bluetooth and both are connected to Router?

Tags: speakers

I want to buy a speaker which connects to Laptop using internet/router Are there any such devices ?

Strictly no Bluetooth.

Comment: WiFi doesn't stream audio in the way you are expecting so please explain the problem you are trying to solve. Somebody might be able to recommend a totally different kind of product than what you are imagining that solves your problem.

Comment: Wifi is networking not audio streaming.  You cant have a dumb speaker to work on wifi.

Comment: can we stream via networking ? we use phone wifi for Air Conditioner similarly can we do that using speaker may be esp or esp now based ?

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/DIY-a-Wi-Fi-Speaker/

Answer (score 0):

They are not cheap.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072KKZ3KD)

> **JBL Playlist 150 - Wireless Speaker with Chromecast Built-In - Black**
> Brand  JBL
> Model Name  JBL Playlist 150 - Black
> Speaker Type    Multi Room
> Connectivity Technology Wi-Fi
> Special Feature Radio
> [image]

There are others

- Amazon Echo Studio
- Sonos Era 100
- Ikea Wi-Fi Symfonisk Bookshelf

Comment: not these type of devices it should have a esp now type chip where we can send data using wifi not chromecast or airplay devices.